# Get Custom Fields from wp-json response

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-json-api

The response for all posts in `wp-json` does not include a couple of Custom Fields that I created in my posts. I call it this way: `/wp-json/posts`

How can I make sure the JSON response also contains my Post Custom Fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/433).

Turns out this is a problem at the mo in Wordpress, but the link has a suggestion fix (amongs others) as such :

```
function json_api_prepare_post( $post_response, $post, $context ) {

  $field = get_field( "field_name", $post['ID'] );

  $post_response['field_name'] = $field;

  return $post_response;
}
add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'json_api_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

You will however have to go through the full post as the above link, s it turns out a lot of people are having this issue, but a number of them got the issue resolved with all the suggestions in the post.

It also appears this question has been asked before. refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132685/json-api-to-show-advanced-custom-fields-wordpress) question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am using "Custom Fields" on a wordpress post, and not "Advanced Custom Fields" wordpress plugin. Hence the "get_field" function is undefined in my case.

Comment: Just guessing, but instead of the get_field line  try "$custom=get_post_custom($post_id);", and then you should be able to access the $custom array eg $custom['field_name'].

Comment: Can you answer how one can modify the wp-json response for a specific post only See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330395/how-to-modify-title-in-wp-json-response-but-only-for-a-specific-post